# Не обновляются стили, сайт на Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Меняю стили на сайте, через фтп сразу правлю, потом захожу через файлзиллу проверяю,изменения сохранились, но на сайте изменений нету,в браузере кеш сбрасываю, может не в той папке правлю [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как кэш в браузере сбрасываешь? Уверен что он сбросился? Лучше добавь в конфиг в отделе `components` в компоненте `assetManager` опцию `'appendTimestamp' => true`

Comment: Прописал,не помогло, кеш удаляю через очистку истории браузера, также захожу через вкладку инкогнито.

Comment: а в браузере метка у файла style.css меняется после изменений? Там метка должна быть `style.css?v=XXXXXXXXX`

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогла очистка кэша, который находится в *runtime/cache*.